# Regex matcher to handle a character or end of line

Tags: java, regex

I would like to create a matching pattern for a situation like this

```
DOMAIN+("Y|A")?
```

I would like the matching options to be only

```
DOMAIN
DOMAINY
DOMAINA
```

but seems like DOMAINX, DOMAINY etc. are matching as well.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, they are matching because you did not specify that the String needed to end with this. `DOMAIN(Y|A)?` is matching `DOMAINX` because it rightfully contains `DOMAIN` followed by nothing (which is accepted since `?` validates 0 or 1 occurence).

You can add this restriction by specifying `$` at the end of the regular expression.

Sample code that shows the result of matches. In your full code, you probably want to compile a `Pattern` instead of doing it each time.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String regex = "DOMAIN(Y|A)?$";
    System.out.println("DOMAIN".matches(regex));  // prints true
    System.out.println("DOMAINX".matches(regex)); // prints false
    System.out.println("DOMAINY".matches(regex)); // prints true
    System.out.println("DOMAINA".matches(regex)); // prints true
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use [word boundaries, `\b`](http://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html), in order to prevent strings such as "DOMAINX" from being matched.

If you just want to handle cases where there are characters *after* the word, add `\b` to the end:

```
DOMAIN(?:Y|A)?\b
```

Otherwise, you could place `\b` around the expression to handle cases where there may be characters at the start/end:

```
\bDOMAIN(?:Y|A)?\b
```

I also made `(?:Y|A)` a non-capturing group and I removed the quotes.

See the [matches here](https://regex101.com/r/cW8sM7/1).

---

However, as your title implies, if you only want to handle characters at the ***end of a line***, use the `$` anchor at the end of your expression:

```
DOMAIN(?:Y|A)?$
```

You may have to add the `m` [(multi-line) flag](http://www.regular-expressions.info/modifiers.html) so that the anchor matches at the start/end of a line rather than at the start/end of the string:

```
(?m)DOMAIN(?:Y|A)?$
```

Answer (score 0):

You need this

```
DOMAIN(Y|A)?
```

If you need it to be a word in text you should anchor it with \b as Josh shows.

Your regex does the following

### DOMAIN+("Y|A")?

```
DOMAIN+("Y|A")?
```

Options: Case sensitive; Exact spacing; Dot doesn’t match line breaks; ^$ don’t match at line breaks; Regex syntax only

- [Match the character string “DOMAI” literally (case sensitive)][1] `DOMAI`
- [Match the character “N” literally (case sensitive)][1] `N+`

  - [Between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)][2] `+`
- [Match the regex below and capture its match into backreference number 1][3] `("Y|A")?`

  - [Between zero and one times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)][4] `?`
  - [Match this alternative (attempting the next alternative only if this one fails)][5] `"Y`

    - [Match the character string “"Y” literally (case sensitive)][1] `"Y`
  - [Or match this alternative (the entire group fails if this one fails to match)][5] `A"`

    - [Match the character string “A"” literally (case sensitive)][1] `A"`